# Cómo crear un botón estilo quicksettings en Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, material-design

Buenas estoy intentado crear un botón estilo quicksettings, es decir un icono al centro dentro de un circulo de color opaco y el texto abajo del circulo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe la existencia de un elemento así?
Lo que había pensado es usar un `TextView` y generar un drawable circular con el icono al centro para luego asignar como `DrawableTop` del `TextView`, pero no ser si hay otra forma mejor para crear un botón así.
En principio solo debe ser botón nada de Toggle como checkbox etc..

Comment: La pregunta no es muy clara. Simplemente quieres un botón redondo o estás buscando un componente que incluya los dos elementos?

Comment: "es decir un icono al centro dentro de un circulo de color opaco y el texto abajo del circulo" es decir todo junto, estoy intentando encontrar si tiene un nombre especifico

Comment: No existe tal componente. En alguna librería externa tal vez sí pero no en material design.